# count with inner join sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi all we have got two tables "Subscriptioninfo , activationinfo"
and the structure is like this for the two tables

**Subscriptioninfo table**

```
   cert_id (int, PK)
   customer_email(string)
   subscription_key(string)
   activated_on (datetime)
```

**activationinfo Table:**

```
    cert_id (int)
    activationcode(string)
    subscription_key(string , FK)
    activated_ts(datetime)
```

the below query will give the count as "**one**" if an entry to **Subscriptioninfo** with the same year and customer email ID (this is fine)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subscriptioninfo WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE year(activated_On) = year(getdate()) AND customer_email =@CustomerEmail
```

we have one sp that will insert the data into both the tables (i.e) one entry to Subscriptioninfo where as four entries to activationinfo

I need to return count as "0" if one entry to subscriptioninfo and two entries to activationinfo

and i need to return count as "1" if one entry to subscriptioninfo and four entries to activationinfo..

Would any one please help on this query how can i get that count with join clause..

Many thanks in advance...

tried with this query but it is giving the activationinfo entry count(i.e) **4**
instead of **1**

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptioninfo csi join activationinfo aci on csi.subscription_key = aci.subscription_key
 WHERE year(Activated_On)  = year(getdate()) AND customer_email = 'xxx@cc.com' group by csi.subscription_key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` statements

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 THEN 1
            WHEN COUNT(*) < 4 THEN 0
       END CountResults
FROM subscriptioninfo csi 
join activationinfo aci on csi.subscription_key = aci.subscription_key
WHERE year(Activated_On)  = year(getdate()) AND customer_email = 'xxx@cc.com' group by csi.subscription_key
```

Comment: if count(*) is less than 4 i need to return 0 as count results ... only if count (*) = 4 only i need to return 1

Answer (score 1):

i just tried to be different and may performance is better,

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY cert_id
            ) rn
    FROM @activationinfo A
    )
SELECT *
    ,1 AS CountResult
FROM @Subscriptioninfo S
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT cert_id
        FROM CTE A
        WHERE s.cert_id = a.cert_id
            AND rn = 4
        )

UNION ALL

SELECT *
    ,0 AS CountResult
FROM @Subscriptioninfo S
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT cert_id
        FROM CTE A
        WHERE s.cert_id = a.cert_id
            AND rn < 4
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. this will give either 1 or 0 right depends on condition ..